# Quadratic equations/modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image] 
Hello! 
I need help with this. I understand the solution, and everything else about the question. What I don't understand is, why does the book say that absolute value of m is greater than 1? I don't get it. Please explain it to me. Thanks

Comment: They are incorrect. They apparently were thinking $m\in (-\infty,-1)\cup (9,\infty)$, despite what they themselves had written. Their conclusion may still be correct.

Comment: Maybe, but still I am not sure. Also, I think it should be, m ≥ 9 or m ≤ 1, i.e. m is greater than or equal to 9 (not just greater than 9, as the book says). Similarly, m should be less than or equal to 1 (not just less than 1, contrary to what the what's written there). Why? Equation 1 will have real roots if it's D ≥ 0, not just greater than zero. Am I correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: They are wrong in their claim that $|m|>1$ for real roots of $t^2-(m-3)t+m=0$. Just check for example $m=0$, then you have $t^2+3t=0$, which clearly have two real roots $t=0$ and $t=-3$. So they made mistake.

Comment: Actually real roots of the given equation belong to [-1, 1], so t = -3 will get rejected. But yeah, maybe, you are right. |m| > 1 may not be correct

Answer (score 1):

The trinomial is $t^2-(m-3)t+m$, and its discriminant is $\Delta=(m-3)^2-4m$. The trinomial has at least one real root iff $\Delta\ge0$, hence $(m-3)^2-4m\ge0$. (that's *not* a strict inequality)

Consider the function $h(m)=(m-3)^3-4m=m^2-10m+9=(m-1)(m-9)$

$h(m)\ge0$ iff ($m\ge1$ and $m\ge9$) or ($m\le1$ and $m\le9$), that is iff $m\in ]-\infty,1]\cup[9,+\infty[$.

And you are **right**, $m$ could be in $[-1,1]$, which means $|m|\le1$.

---

It's easy to check that $|m|\le1$ would lead to solutions of the initial equation. For instance, with $m=0$, you get

$$\sin^2 t+3\sin t=\sin t(\sin t+3)$$

And this is zero for $t=k\pi$.

---

Let's try to finish the proof anyway.

**If** $m\ge9$, then the product of the roots of $f(t)=0$ is greater than $1$, and one root lies in $[-1,1]$. Hence the other does not. That means that there is a change of sign between $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$, or $f(-1)f(1)\le0$.

Then $(1-m+3+m)(1+m-3+m)\le0$, or $4(2m-2)\le0$, that is $m\le1$. Contradiction, as we supposed $m\ge9$.

So we must indeed have $m\le1$.

Now, if $m\le1$, is it certain the equation $f(t)=0$ has a solution $t\in[-1,1]$? Yes, because $f(1)f(-1)=(1-m+3+m)(1+m-3+m)=4(2m-2)\le0$, and the intermediate value theorem tells us $f(t)=0$ must have a root in $[-1,1]$.

Note that $m=1$ is also a valid value, so the inequality is not $m<1$ but $m\le1$. Then $f(t)=t^2+2t+1=(t+1)^2$, which is zero for $t=-1$. And $\sin x=-1$ for $x=-\frac\pi2+2k\pi$.

Comment: But f(1) f(-1) ≤ 0 is true for the first case, when m > 9 => |m| > 9, hence both roots can't lie in [-1,1]. As for the second case, when m < -1, I don't think we can make use of f(1) f(-1) ≤ 0 ?? Because it was true for m > 9 ?

Comment: @πtimese For $m>9$ it leads to a contradiction, but for $m<1$ the intermediate value theorem tells us there is a root in $[-1,1]$, because we have $f(1)f(-1)\le0$.

Answer (score 1):

[image] [image] 
Solved it finally! I still don't fully understand why |m| > 1, but this is how I solved it. Is it correct?